# Diferença entre o método create e fill - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu estava desenvolvendo um web service com laravel, e percebi que posso salvar os dados no meu banco de duas formas:

```
Product::create($request->all());
```

ou então:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->fill($request->all());
$product->save();
```

A minha dúvida é se há alguma diferença entre essas duas formas. E quando eu deveria usar uma ou a outra.

Answer (score 8):

Os dois métodos fazem as mesmas coisas, com uma única diferença:

> If you already have a model instance, you may use the fill method to
>   populate it with an array of attributes:
>
> ```
> $flight->fill(['name' => 'Flight 22']);
> ```

Ou seja você usa o `fill` caso já tenha instanciado o `model`, se não continue utilizando o `create`.

**Update**

> Errado. Os dois não fazem a mesma coisa. O fill apenas preenche os
>   atributos no model. O create cria os dados. Basicamente, o create usa
>   o fill internamente e, em seguida, chama save. Se você usar o fill sem
>   save, os registros no banco de dados não são afetados.

Fonte: [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: -1 Errado. Os dois **não fazem a mesma coisa**. O `fill` apenas preenche os atributos no model. O `create` cria os dados. Basicamente, o `create` usa o `fill` internamente e, em seguida, chama `save`. Se você usar o `fill` sem `save`, os registros no banco de dados não são afetados.

Comment: Obrigado, @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 6):

O método `fill` significa "preencher".

Ele apenas preenche as informações do seu Model.

O fill usado assim:

```
$usuario = Usuario::first();

$usuario->fill(['nivel_id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Wallace']);
```

É o mesmo que fazer assim:

```
$usuario = Usuario::first();

$usuario->nivel_id = 1;
$usuario->nome = 'Wallace';
```

Se você apenas chamar `fill`, nada ocorrerá no banco, mas apenas na instância do seu Model.

Você precisa chamar o método `save` para que as informações sejam sincronizadas no banco de dados.

O `create` serve para criar um registro. O `create` sempre cria, diferentemente do `save`. O `save` cria se não existir e, se existir, atualiza.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro exemplo de código, cria uma instância da classe e pega os dados passados e grava

```
//instancia uma classe Produto
//método atribui os valores configurados no fillable
//grava um novo registro na sua tabela e desenvolve uma instância desse registro
Product::create($request->all());
```

a outra forma serve para atribuir valores novos para dados inexistente ou até existente, ou seja, o segundo código pode ser utilizado para savar um registro novo ou até alterar dados de um registro que já existe, chamando por fim o método `save()`, exemplo

```
$product = new Product();
$product->fill($request->all());
$product->save();
```

ou

```
// buscando registro de número 1
$product = Produto::find(1) 
// verificando se encontrou o produto
if ($produto)
{
    //atribuindo novos valores ou apenas alguns valores
    $product->fill($request->all());
}
// salvando os dados passados
$product->save();
```

note, que o método `fill` só aceita os valores configurados no `fillable`, mas, *não é obrigado passar todos os valores e só serão alterados ou inseridos os valores passados* e também os valores passados por esse método não garante que os dados serão salvos, porque, por fim deve chamar o método `save()`.

Na mesma linha do `create` que já faz de uma só vez a criação de um novo registro, tem o método `update` que tem a finalidade de atribuir os valores e logo após salvar as alterações, exemplo:

```
// buscando registro de número 1
$product = Produto::find(1) 
// verificando se encontrou o produto
if ($produto)
{
    //atribuindo novos valores ou apenas alguns valores
    // e salvando as alterações (sem precisa chamar método save())
    $product->update($request->all());
}
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel: updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates)
- [Laravel: mass-assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Ahh, então quer dizer que o fill também serve pra atualizar caso eu tenha a instância do produto, caso eu não tenha instância, ele cria. Pelo visto substitui o create e o update muito bem.

Comment: o método `fill` serve para preencher uma classe de valores, tanto no modo novo registro, tanto quanto edição de registro ... @MarceloTorres só que os dados só são realmente salvos a partir do método `->save()`. Já `Create` e `Update` ele faz o processo de criação e/ou atualização na mesma chamada do método