# Como atualizar um valor específico sem modificar os outros PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, cakephp, phpmyadmin

Olá, boa tarde. O meu problema é o seguinte: No projeto que estou fazendo tenho uma tabela com alguns produtos e que estão associados a remessas, por exemplo, **(feijão, farinha, arroz)** da remessa **37** e **(feijão, farinha, arroz)** da remessa **38**. Eu posso incluir/modificar os preços de todos os produtos + todas remessa ao mesmo tempo ou apenas um produto em especifico de uma remessa. Na primeira opção está ocorrendo tudo ok, já na segunda opção é que mora o problema. Eu clico em **modificar preço do arroz** e quando modifico/salvo, os outros preços do **feijão e farinha** ficam como **NULL** no banco de dados. Vale lembrar que os produtos são salvos com o preço **NULL** quando registrado a remessa e posteriormente de forma manual edita-se os preços.

Segue o código:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $numberPrice= $request->all();
        foreach ($numberPrice['numero_rem'] as $key => $rem) {
                            $price = Price::where('numero_rem', '=', $rem)->first();
                            $price->update([
                                'feijao' => $numberPrice['feijao'][$key] ?? null,
                                'farinha' => $numberPrice['farinha'][$key] ?? null,
                                'arroz' => $numberPrice['arroz'][$key] ?? null,
                                'leite' => $numberPrice['leite'][$key] ?? null,
                            ]);
                    }
     }
```

No código acima eu associo o **conjunto de produtos** a um valor **x** de remessas, para quando for alterar o preço do **arroz da remessa 37** não alterar o preço do **arroz da remessa 38**. Em seguida salvo os valores que eu modifiquei e os que não mexi continua como **NULL**. Na prática era para acontecer isso, mas quando eu salvo a modificação (o feijão, por exemplo, que tinha preço 6,99 fica como **NULL**) sendo que eu mexi apenas no arroz.

Abaixo segue as imagens retratando o que eu faria manualmente.
**1ª Imagem:** Tela inicial.
**2ª Imagem:** Select e suas opções.
**3ª Imagem:** Todos os preços dos produtos e cada uma de suas remessas.
**4ª Imagem:** Preço de um produto em esfecifico (feijão) e suas remessas.

[image: essa imagem é mostra a tela inicial]

[image: essa imagem mostra o select e suas opções]

[image: essa imagem mostra todos os campos dos prodrutos e suas respectivas remessas]

[image: essa imagem mostra um campo especifico (fijão) e suas remessas]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como vc já possui o model salvo em `$price` vc pode usar o método `fill()` da seguinte forma:

```
$price = Price::where('numero_rem', '=', $rem)->first();
$price->fill($request->all())->save();
```

Dessa forma, todos os campos que vierem no seu `$request` serão usados para atualizar o `$price`. Importante destacar que se no request estão vindo valores  NULL, eles tb serão usados para popular seu model.

Segue algumas referencias:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976818/laravel-how-to-update-multiple-records-using-request-all
[Diferença entre o método create e fill - laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293351/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-m%C3%A9todo-create-e-fill-laravel)

Comment: Call to a member function fill() on null, me retornou esse erro.

Comment: Tentei escrever $price->fill([
                                'feijao' => $numberPrice['feijao'][$key] ?? null,
                                'farinha' => $numberPrice['farinha'][$key] ?? null,
                                'arroz' => $numberPrice['arroz'][$key] ?? null,
                            ])->save;. Mas também acontece o erro postado na pergunta, não entendo porque quando seleciono a opção de preencher apenas um produto acaba zerando os outros. Estou lendo a documentação e fazendo testes, mas ta osso.

Comment: Baseado no seu comentario, por algum motivo seu request veio nulo, vc consegue debugar dentro do foreach para ver como o request esta?

Comment: Vou fazer isso e já te retorno o que apareceu.

Comment: @OziasJunior conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Sim, um colega me ajudou a resolver o meu problema. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, desculpe a demora em te responder.